# Hacer un POST con JPA con datos ya existentes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa

tengo el siguiente problema, la cosa es que tengo una entidad:

```
package com.innovart.cpve.user.persistence.entity;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "CPVE_USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDUSERS")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long idUser;

    @Column(name = "IDROLES")
    private Long idRol;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "GRANTS")
    private String grant;

    @Column(name = "STATE_ACTIVE")
    private Integer stateActive;

    @Column(name = "REGISTRATION_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

}
```

La cosa es que este back esta conectado a una DB Oracle, en la que ya tengo unos cuantos usuarios registrados, pero estos los ingrese a travez de un script de Mockaroo, y cuando intento hacer un save de un nuevo usuario a través de un servicio Rest me lanza este error:

```
2021-12-22 11:03:53.156 ERROR 23148 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CPVE"."CPVE_USERS"."IDUSERS")
```

Claro entiendo que el problema es que como tengo registros ya creados, Spring intenta crear un nuevo usuario, pero no "sabe" que tiene que iniciar desde el PK 500 por ejemplo.

¿sera que hay alguna forma de que automáticamente Spring conozca el dato de donde va el PK de usuarios y lo continúe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era, que al usar el "strategy = GenerationType.AUTO" Hibernate crea en mi base de datos Oracle una secuencia llamada Hibernate_Sequence, la cual es la que define cual va a ser el valor del "idUsers", decidí crear una secuencia propia para que lleve el conteo desde el valor que yo decida. Aca dejo el codigo de como quedaria esta parte de la entidad:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "IDUSERS")
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "sequence-generator"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "sequence-generator",
        sequenceName = "SEC_IDUSER",
        initialValue = 501,
        allocationSize=1
)
private Long idUser;
```

Así quedaría el código de mi entidad, y ahora si ya me permite guardar nuevos usuarios. <3 <3 <3 <3  Muchas gracias a todos.